# Question about the definition of parametric derivative

Tags: derivatives, parametric

Consider the parametric equations $x=x(t),y=y(t)$, then the parametric derivative is
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}, \text{ provided }\frac{dx}{dt}\not=0.$$

My question is: Is the derivative not defined at $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$? Especially if I write $x(t)=cos(t),y(t)=cos(t)^2$, then is $y'(x)$ not defined at $x=0$?

Comment: It's not that simple!  Of course, if x= cos(t) and y= cos^2(t) then y= x^2 and dy/dx= 2x which certainly exists (and is equal to 0 at x= 0).  The problem is that x= f(t) and y= g(t) is not a valid parameterization where dx/dt= 0.

Comment: @GeorgeIvey I see. Thank you!